# array of events in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, events

basically:

```
public delegate void RecvCommandHandler (ChatApplication sender, byte[] content);
event RecvCommandHandler[] commands = new RecvCommandHandler[255];
```

I want to activate a different method/function for each command number, but I am really uncertain of the syntax. How am I supposed to do it?

I think I'll go with just an array of delegates for this one, but the question is still interesting.

Comment: Could you not use one Event (or delegate) with an eventArgs specifying what do do?

Comment: not unless I want a lengthly switch-case code without an option to check for null.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's really no concept of an array of events - it's like talking about an array of properties. Events are really just methods which let you subscribe and unsubscribe handlers. If you need to be able to do this by index, I suggest you just have a pair of methods. (`AddCommandHandler(int, RecvCommandHandler)` and `RemoveCommandHandler(int, RecvCommandHandler)`). That won't support the normal event handling syntactic sugar, of course, but I don't see that there's a lot of alternative.

Comment: Just remark to intro -- I have no problem with Action[]. So it is possible to have array of methods, the problem is rather that event in C# behaves like some kind of hybrid of method and object. It should be normal class with un-/register methods and call.

Comment: Would be neat if we had such thing. If I want to subscribe/unsubscribe  to have something like an exit hook it takes a bunch of events (some depending on execution context: IIS , WPF application, console program. An array/IEnumerable of them could be injected without knowing them upfront in any library.

Answer (score 19):

You could create an array of a class with operator overloading to simulate the behavior you are interested in...

```
public delegate void EventDelegate(EventData kEvent);

public class EventElement
{
    protected event EventDelegate eventdelegate;

    public void Dispatch(EventData kEvent)
    {
        if (eventdelegate != null)
        {
            eventdelegate(kEvent);
        }
    }

    public static EventElement operator +(EventElement kElement, EventDelegate kDelegate)
    {
        kElement.eventdelegate += kDelegate;
        return kElement;
    }

    public static EventElement operator -(EventElement kElement, EventDelegate kDelegate)
    {
        kElement.eventdelegate -= kDelegate;
        return kElement;
    }
}

public EventElement[] commands = new EventElement[255];

commands[100] += OnWhatever;
commands[100].Dispatch(new EventData());
commands[100] -= OnWhatever;
```

Answer (score 2):

The other option is to specify and index in the delegate prototype and have one event handler that "delegates" to the others, e.g.:

```
public delegate void RecvCommandHandler (int id, ChatApplication sender, byte[] content);

// ...

private RecvCommandHandler[] internalhandlers;

public void MyCommandHandler(int id, ChatApplication sender, byte[] content)
{
    internalHandlers[id](id, sender, content);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just looking for the same answer, however my class is also event sender for WPF, so it should look as much as normal C#/WPF event sender class. So I simply added this:

To sender:

- enum with properties name -- this is lame workaround for lack of nameof
- one additional method to record requests

To receiver:

- request event for given enum

The code, sender:

```
    public enum Properties
    {
        NetworkFileName,
        DatasetFileName,
        LearningWatch
    }

    private string network_filename;
    public string NetworkFileName 
    {
        get { return network_filename; }
        private set 
        {
            if (network_filename != value)
            {
                network_filename = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(Properties.NetworkFileName.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    public void OnChange(Properties prop, Action<object, PropertyChangedEventArgs> action)
    {
        PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler((obj, args) => { if (args.PropertyName == prop.ToString()) action(obj, args); });
    }
```

And to the receiver:

```
    private void OnNetworkLoaded(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SetTitle();
    }

        ...
        ExpManager.OnChange(ExperimentManager.Properties.DatasetFileName, OnDatasetLoaded);
```

It is still ugly, but at least:

- I don't have to deal with "ifs" in receiver
- I can easily create multiple event handlers
- it is compatible with WPF
- no magic strings (I hate those)

Disadvantage:

- obsfuscation ruins this (but I have special class for that case, this project is just for me, so no problem here)