# Collection of Events

Tags: c#, .net, events, collections

I am using events as a publisher/subscriber pattern in c#. However I dont know at design time how many publishers my program will be using. I would like to dynamically add events to either a class directly, or more plausibly to a collection/dictionary containing the events.

Are either of these scenarios possible using C#?

Comment: possible duplicate of [array of events in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987050/array-of-events-in-c)

Comment: If you don't know at design time then you won't know at runtime either.  I can only imagine you got it backwards, you won't know how many subscribers there will be for an event.

Comment: I will know at runtime. The software is for message passing in a simulation, and the concept is that you have one publisher for each area in the simulation world, but the number of areas is unknown as the total space is not fixed at design time. Each area is loaded from disk at runtime with a publisher for each.

However, the mediator solution posted below may be appropriate. I need to explore it in depth, but it appears to be a good workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a mediator that your publishers publish to and that your subscribers subscribe to.  For example:

```
public class Mediator
{
    public static readonly Mediator Current = new Mediator();
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> EventRaised;
    public void RaiseEvent(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (EventRaised!=null) 
            EventRaised(sender, eventArgs);
    }
}
public class PublisherEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string SomeData { get; set; }
}
public class Publisher
{
    public void Publish(string data)
    {
        Mediator.Current.RaiseEvent(this, new PublisherEventArgs() { SomeData = data} );
    }
}
public class Subscriber
{
    public Subscriber()
    {
        Mediator.Current.EventRaised += HandlePublishedEvent;
    }

    private void HandlePublishedEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(e is PublisherEventArgs)
        {
            string data = ((PublisherEventArgs)e).SomeData;
            // todo: do something here
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure you implement IDisposable on your subscriber (its not in my example) so that it unsubscribes from the Mediator during dispose.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to disconnect the event from it's source in order to do this.  This is commonly done with an event aggregator; it manages clients that want to publish events as well as those that want to subscribe to events.  All of this decouples the publishers from the listeners and allows you to do what you are describing.

[Prism has an event aggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122%28v=PandP.40%29.aspx#sec11) out-of-the-box that you can use in the form of the `IEventAggregator` interface.