# Dynamic created event in c#

Tags: c#, dynamic, delegates, eventhandler

I have a dynamical create button object where I want it to send an event to the mainform when I click on a button inside this object.

I have the code like this :

```
class Class1
{
    internal class FObj_BtnRow
    {
        private Button[] _Btnmembers;
        internal event EventHandler<SelValue_EArgs>[] e_BtnMember; //subscribe to a change  

        internal class SelValue_EArgs : EventArgs//events args (selected value)
        {//return arguments in events
            internal SelValue_EArgs(Boolean ivalue) { refreshed = ivalue; }//ctor
            internal Boolean refreshed { get; set; }//accessors
        }
        private Boolean[] _ActONOFFValue; //Pump=0, valveInput = 1, Shower = 3, Washtool = 4 , WashWPcs = 5
        private Boolean ActONOFFValue(int number)
        {
            _ActONOFFValue[number] = !_ActONOFFValue[number];
            {
                if (e_BtnMember[number] != null && number == 0) e_BtnMember[number](this, new SelValue_EArgs(_ActONOFFValue[number]));
            }
            return _ActONOFFValue[number];
        }
        public FObj_BtnRow(String[] TxtBtn, String UnitName)//ctor
        { 
            _Btnmembers = new Button[TxtBtn.Length];
            e_BtnMember = new EventHandler<SelValue_EArgs>[TxtBtn.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < TxtBtn.Length / 2; i++)
            {
                _Btnmembers[i].Click += new EventHandler(_Btnmembers_Click);
            }
        }
        protected virtual void _Btnmembers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int index = Array.IndexOf(_Btnmembers, (Button)sender);
            ActONOFFValue(index);
        }

    }

}
```

But in the line : internal event EventHandler[] e_BtnMember; 
the compiler told me that I should use a delegate. I don't understand good this remark, could you help me?
At the end the mainform should only subscribe to the event button click it wants.

And then in main we could use it to now when a button in the object multibutton row is clicked... like this:

```
public void main()
{
String[] txtbtn = new String[] { "btn1", "btn2", "btn3" };
FObj_BtnRow thisbtnrow = new FObj_BtnRow(txtbtn);
thisbtnrow.e_BtnMember[0] += new EventHandler<FObj_BtnRow.SelValue_EArgs>   (btnmember0haschanged);
}
    public void btnmember0haschanged(object sender,     FObj_BtnRow.SelValue_EArgs newvalue)
    {
        bool thisnewvalue = newvalue.refreshed;
    }
```

Can you help me?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Could you please reduce the code to the minimal amount required to demonstrate this issue?

Comment: I'll do it. Thanks.

Comment: The line `internal event EventHandler<SelValue_EArgs>[] e_BtnMember` is an array of delegates. It is not a delegate. The `event` keyword can only preceed a delegate,

Comment: @Enigmativity: to be precise, the `event` keyword can only precede a delegate _type_. A delegate is the instance of such a type. But yes, the problem is fundamentally as you describe. **To the OP:** you need to reduce your problem to a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you're trying to do. It's not clear at all what you expected to happen with the array syntax in your declaration. I'm sure a suitable alternative can be offered as an answer, but what that alternative should be is open to broad interpretation at the moment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [array of events in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987050/array-of-events-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by myself, thanks for your advices.

Code

```
 class Class1
 {
internal class FObj_BtnRowtest
{
    private Button[] _Btnmembers;
    public delegate void del_Btnmember(Boolean value);
    public del_Btnmember[] btnvaluechanged;

    internal class SelValue_EArgs : EventArgs//events args (selected value)
    {//return boolean arguments in events
        internal SelValue_EArgs(Boolean ivalue) { refreshed = ivalue; }//ctor
        internal Boolean refreshed { get; set; }//accessors
    }
    private Boolean[] _ActONOFFValue; 
    private Boolean ActONOFFValue(int number)
    {
        _ActONOFFValue[number] = !_ActONOFFValue[number];
        return _ActONOFFValue[number];
    }
    public FObj_BtnRowtest(int numofbtn, String UnitName)//ctor
    {
        _Btnmembers = new Button[numofbtn];
        btnvaluechanged = new del_Btnmember[numofbtn];
        _ActONOFFValue = new bool[numofbtn];
        for (int i = 0; i < numofbtn / 2; i++)
        {
           _Btnmembers[i].Click += new EventHandler(_Btnmembers_Click);
        }
    }
    protected virtual void _Btnmembers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int index = Array.IndexOf(_Btnmembers, (Button)sender);
        if (btnvaluechanged[index] != null) btnvaluechanged[index](ActONOFFValue(index));
    }
 }
}
```

And then in main

```
  thisrow = new Class1.FObj_BtnRowtest(4,"thisunittest");//4 buttons 
  thisrow.btnvaluechanged[0] += new Class1.FObj_BtnRowtest.del_Btnmember(valuetesthaschanged);//to subscribe to btn0 change
```

using delegates make it easier. and yes we do need those kinds of stuffs to make code clearer and faster to developp.

Thanks all!!