# How to fix "event must be of a delegate type" error? (event array inside interface) C#

Tags: c#, arrays, events

The compiler is giving me this error when I try to make an array of events within an interface:

**Error CS0066: event must be of a delegate type**

```
public interface IEventSystem
{
    public event Action<EventInfo, Property>[] onEvent;
}

public class EventSystem : IEventSystem
{
    public event Action<EventInfo, Property>[] onEvent = new Action<EventInfo, Property>[(int)Type.Count + 1];
}
```

The solution that Microsoft gives on their website:

> // to fix the error, remove the event declaration and the
> // EventHandler class declaration, and uncomment the following line
> // public delegate void EventHandler();

But it does not work with interfaces, I get this other error: **Interface cannot contain field**

Does anyone know how to fix this error?
Thank you!!

Comment: Why do you want an _array_ of events? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987050/array-of-events-in-c) perhaps?

Comment: Because I have many different types of events. It is easier to handle if they are in an array. Thanks for the link!!

Comment: In addition, try removing the `public` from your interface. Not sure if that might be affecting your compiler complaints in the class implementation of the interface as well.